# Rails and jQuery - how do you get server-side validation errors to your view after an ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Ive searched this site but questions are usually regarding doing client-side validations or for different frameworks.

I have a tasks list whose items can be edited inline. Upon submitting the inline edit form the item is updated all thanks to jQuery, ajax and rails.

But I want to handle bad input from the user. HTML requests redisplay the view and errors are displayed thanks to rails helpers.

But how do I insert that information after an ajax call?

Heres my update method in my controller

```
def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
        flash[:notice] = 'Task was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@task) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @task.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        #format.js ...hmmm... either go to js.erb file or do stuff inline
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do

```
format.js { render :update { |page| page.replace_html "inline_form", :partial => "form" }
```

where `inline_form` is the id of the element inside which your inline editor sits. The `form` partial can contain an `error_messages_for` statement and the actual field that you are showing.

That way, if validation fails, the element with your editor will be updated with the same editor, but displaying validation errors.